# Reduce dataframe to only the rows that have changed

Tags: python, pandas

I have an old dataframe and new dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_old = pd.DataFrame({
        "col1": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
        "col2": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
        "col3": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
    }, columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"])

df_new = pd.DataFrame({
        "col1": ["a", "b", "c", "e", "f"],
        "col2": [1.0, 2.0, 3.5, 5.0, 6.0],
        "col3": [1.0, 4.2, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0]
    }, columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"])

# Expected data
df_changed = pd.DataFrame({
        "col1": ["b", "c", "d", "f"],
        "col2": [2.0, 3.5, np.NaN, 6.0],
        "col3": [4.2, 3.0, np.NaN, 6.0]
    }, columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"])

print(df_old)
print(df_new)
print(df_changed)
```

I would like to have the rows that changed (either col2 of col3), got added, and were removed between old df and new df.  In my actual data, col1 is unique, so it can be an index if needed.

**EDIT**
If I set col1 as the index

```
df_old.set_index('col1', inplace=True)
df_new.set_index('col1', inplace=True)
```

I can run

```
print(df_new.ne(df_old))

       col2   col3
col1
a     False  False
b     False   True
c      True  False
d      True   True
e     False  False
f      True   True
```

I can then create a diff df like so

```
df_diff = df_new.ne(df_old)
df_diff = df_diff[df_diff.col2 | df_diff.col3]
```

I'm not sure how to relate this back to dataframe with data though.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Sorry @nidabdella.  Please see EDIT for what I have sovar.  Most of it I've only just figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were not that far of the solution. once done `set_index` and the `ne` operation, get a series with `any` along the columns to get True per row with at least one True, and `reindex` df_new with only the wanted values

```
df_old = df_old.set_index('col1')
df_new = df_new.set_index('col1')

s = df_new.ne(df_old).any(axis=1) # get True for rows with at least one True
print(s)
# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2     True
# 3     True
# 4     True
# dtype: bool

df_changed = df_new.reindex(s.index[s]).reset_index()
print(df_changed)
  col1  col2  col3
0    b   2.0   4.2
1    c   3.5   3.0
2    d   NaN   NaN
3    f   6.0   6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
g=df_new.set_index('col1')#Reset df_new's index


#subtract the datframes after resetting index and use the loc accessor to filter unwanted rows
g.loc[~(df_old.set_index('col1').sub(df_new.set_index('col1'))[['col2','col3']].reset_index()




  col1  col2  col3
0    b   2.0   4.2
1    c   3.5   3.0
2    f   6.0   6.0
```